# c# type identifier exists but I'm still getting an error that it's expected

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am writing my first c# algorithm challenge and I am running into a problem. I have added type identifiers to all my variables but I'm still getting an error that an identifier is expected. I'm not sure how I can solve this when the actual type identifier is there. Here is my code and here is the error log.

```
public class ShortLongShort
{
  public static string Solution(string a, string b)
  {
    string long = a;
    string short = b;
    if(a.Length < b.Length) {
        short = a;
        long = b;
    }
    return short+long+short;
  }
}
```

```
src/Solution.cs(5,12): error CS1001: Identifier expected
src/Solution.cs(5,12): error CS1002: ; expected
src/Solution.cs(5,17): error CS1001: Identifier expected
src/Solution.cs(6,12): error CS1001: Identifier expected
src/Solution.cs(6,12): error CS1002: ; expected
src/Solution.cs(6,18): error CS1001: Identifier expected
src/Solution.cs(8,15): error CS1001: Identifier expected
src/Solution.cs(9,14): error CS1001: Identifier expected
src/Solution.cs(11,12): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'short'
src/Solution.cs(11,18): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'long'
src/Solution.cs(11,23): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'short'
```

Comment: [`long` and `short`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) are [reserved words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) and cannot be used as identifiers. Try either `@long`/`@short` ([verbatim identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)) or renaming them `longString`/`shortString`.

Answer (score 1):

long and short are types, use different names for these variables.

Answer (score 1):

"long" and "short" are boths keywords for types (long being a 64-bit integer, and short being a 16 bit one). Change the names of the "long" and "short" variables to something else, such as "longValue" and "shortValue".

[Read more here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)